# How will Facebook like buttons work on 3rd party websites, when Google abolishes 3rd party cookies?

Tags: cookies, facebook-like

Safari & Firefox have already stopped using third-party cookies, & Chrome is going to do the same by 2022.

Many 3rd party websites have Facebook like buttons on them, how are these buttons likely to work going forward? Could Facebook use an alternative solution to third-party cookies?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm interested in this question as well. @mattnewbie, did you find the answer?

Comment: Also, Google postponed the abolition of cookies until the end of 2023. So, you can fix this information in your question.